# Reducing and exporting to CSV returns duplicated rows with 0 values for calculated NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have table of 10 points that I want to extract the mean and standard deviation of NDVI from sentinel within a buffered area for a time period. I am running into a problem where when I reduce it and try to export it to a csv, I get a lot of duplicated rows with 0 values for the calculated statistics.

[image: Example output]

Here is the code I am working with:

```
print(sample);

// buffering around points
var bufferPoly = function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(2500);   // adjust for buffer size in meters
};

var zone = sample.map(bufferPoly); 

print(zone);

// Importing sentinel and cropping around feature collection
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filterDate('2020-10-01', '2020-10-05')                  
    .select([
      'B4','B8',
    ])
    .filterBounds(zone)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(zone)});

var count = sentinel.size(); // seeing how many bands there are...shouldn't be too many
print('Bands of sentinel: ', count);

print(sentinel); // we can see what is actually here, it is a collection of 12 images each having two bands

// Calculating NDVI for each image

// NDVI Function
function ndvi(im) {
  return im.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']);
}

// mapping the ndvi function over all images
var ndvi = sentinel.map(ndvi);

var count = ndvi.size(); // seeing how many bands there are
print('Bands of ndvi: ', count); 

print(ndvi); //We can see that it is a collection of 12 images with one ndvi band

//Now to reduce the image collection in a summary

//now extracting to the polygon

var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

var scale = ndvi.first().projection().nominalScale();

var reduced = ndvi.map(function(image){
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection:zone , 
    reducer:reducers, 
    scale: scale
  });
});

var count = reduced.size(); // There are 12 bands here
print('Bands of reduced: ', count);

print(reduced);

var table = reduced.flatten();

var count = table.size(); // There are 120 bands here
print('Bands of table: ', count); 

print(table);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table,
  description:'Example',
  fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

For some reason, this is giving me 12 duplicated rows per the original row in the table. Any idea what is happening here?

link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fddlawton%2FAUS_SOILS_TEST%3AExtraction_code

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.reduceRegions()`, you are reducing `ndvi` over every feature in your feature collection `sample`. So the first 12 rows contain `ndvi` (size: 12 images) reduced over the your first feature, the next 12 rows are reduced over your second feature, etc. Since you have 120 rows, `sample` must have a size of 10.

I am guessing that the ndvi statistics for some rows are blank because there is no overlapping area between the image and feature; when filtering an image collection with `.filterBounds()`, images will be retained if there is partial overlap with the `ee.Geometry` you are filtering by.

How do you filter an `ee.ImageCollection` for images that contain multiple geometries? One idea is to create a list of filters that checks the intersection of the image with multiple coordinates. Assuming that `sample` is a `ee.FeatureCollection` with a MultiPoint geometry (based on comments in your code),

```
var filterboundslist = ee.List(
  
  // map over list of coordinates 
  sample.geometry().coordinates().map(function(point){
    
    return ee.Filter.bounds(ee.Geometry.Point(point))
  })
)

// filter image collection
var sentinel_filt = sentinel.filter(filterboundslist)
```

Depending on the distribution of your sample areas, it is possible that no image intersects with all coordinates at once, in which case `sentinel_filt` would have a size of zero.

Comment: so is there a way to filter the image collection to the points of interest without retaining the null data?

Comment: @Douglas see my editted answer